# Spacy to tensorflow lite

Tags: tensorflow, spacy, spacy-3

I created a spacy model with ner and text classification. This model works great but I'm wondering if I can export it to tensorflow Lite to test it on a mobile device. Do you think it's possible ?
I search with Thinc but I don't find a solution.